# Representations of Lie groups over finite fields as direct summand in tensor products

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I have been reading that if $G$ is a Lie group and $V$ is a faithful and complex representation of $G$, then each irreducible representation $W$ of $G$ occurs as a direct summand in the tensor product of some number of copies of $V$. Can we conclude the same if $V$ is a faithful representation on a finite field and $W$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ on the same field instead of $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that need to be clarified a bit here:

- In the Lie group case you need to assume compactness in order for the irreducibles to arise as direct summands as opposed to subquotients.
- Even in the compact case you need to take tensor products of both $V$ and its dual $V^*$, not just $V$.   If $G$ is finite or compact semisimple you are okay with just $V$, but even for say $S^1$ you need $V^*$.
- Connected groups can't act nontrivially on finite sets, so any action of a Lie group $G$ on $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ will factor through the component group $G/G^0$.

Still though, we can salvage at least a version of this: If $G$ is a finite group and $V$ is a faithful representation of $G$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ then any irreducible representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ arises as a subquotient of $V^{\otimes n}$ for some $n$.

The proof of this fact that I know follows the proof outline of the complex case suggested in Problem 3.26 in [Introduction to representation theory](http://math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/replect.pdf) by Etingof et al.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I have a finite group $G$.